# Flutter : get parent data of sub-collection from firestore

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I needed to get the parent document data of subcollection from firestore. I used the collection group query to get the sub-collection.

Comment: where is your code? what error are you receiving?

Comment: There's no error, I wanted to perform a task which I don't have an idea of how to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.parent()` will do from a [document reference](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/DocumentReference/parent.html) or a [collection reference](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/CollectionReference/parent.html).