# Having issues with showing subcollection with dynamically added fields in firestore

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I made a list of patients, with a subcollection of checkouts(pregledi in my language) and that subcollection is filled dynamicaly when a doctor makes a checkout with a date as a field name and checkout as a value. Here is a function that does that

```
_addField(String fieldName, String description, String id){

FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('pacijenti')
.doc(id).collection('pregledi').doc(id).
set({
fieldName: description
},SetOptions(merge: true));}
```

The issue I'm having is how to show a list of all checkouts when I click on patients name. I tried making a different page, but that was a dead end since I cant fetch the data because I'm missing the unique field name(because every checkout is named differently when its added). Sorry if my question is not clear, its my first one. Here's some more source code, and what I tried to do.

My checkoutPage

```
 class _ChecksScreenState extends State<ChecksScreen> {

  final Color primaryColor = Color(0xff18203d);
  final Color secondaryColor = Color(0xff232c51);
  final Color logoGreen = Color(0xff25bcbb);
  
  TextEditingController dateCheckController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController checkoutController = TextEditingController();

  List<dynamic> checkouts = [];

  getPatient() async {
    QuerySnapshot querySnapshot = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('pacijenti')
    

        .doc(FieldPath.documentId.toString()).collection('pregledi').get();
        var response = querySnapshot.docs;
        return response;
      }
      @override
      void initState() {
        getPatient().then((data) {
          setState(() {
            checkouts = data;
          });
        });
        super.initState();
      }
    
      CollectionReference ref = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('pacijenti').doc(FieldPath.documentId.toString()).collection('pregledi');
      late DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Pregledi",
            style: GoogleFonts.openSans(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 32)),
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        elevation: 0,
        actions: [
          IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.note_add_rounded, size: 32),
              onPressed: (){
                  showDialog(
                    context: context,
                    builder: (context) => Dialog(
                      child: Container(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
                        color: primaryColor,
                        child: ListView(
                          shrinkWrap: true,
                          children: <Widget> [
                            _buildTextField(dateCheckController, "Datum"),
                            SizedBox(height: 20),
                            _buildTextField(checkoutController, "Pregled"),
                            SizedBox(height: 20),
                            MaterialButton(
                              child: Padding(
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                                child: Text(
                                  'Dodaj pregled',
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      color: Colors.white
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ) ,
                              color: logoGreen,
                              onPressed: () {
                                _addField(dateCheckController.text, checkoutController.text, ref.id);
                                Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(
                                    context,
                                    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => ChecksScreen()),
                                        (route) => false);
                              },
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  );
                },
              ),
          IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.folder_open_rounded, size:32),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => ListScreen()),
                        (route) => false);
              }),
          SizedBox(width: 10,),
        ],
      ),
      backgroundColor: primaryColor,
        body: Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: checkouts.length > 0
            ? ListView.builder(
            itemCount: checkouts.length,
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index){
              return GestureDetector(
               onTap: () {
                 Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(Checkout.routeName,
                     arguments: checkouts[index]);
               },
                child: ListTile(
                  title: Container(
                    child:
                      Text(checkouts[index][dateCheckController.text],
                        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 20),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              );
            },
      ): Center(
      child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
    ),
    ),
);
```

}

The issue is that I'm trying to show every checkout, but every field in collection has a different name, because user is adding checkout fields dynamically. I tried doing that with a dateCheckController that I use for adding checkouts, but I know that's not viable solution. Should I assign String name for that controller and try fetching the fields like that? I'm baffled.

[Fields that I want to show, but they don't have an unique name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lrZ1i.png)

Comment: Your description of the problem is a little confusing, so I am not sure I understood. But what you could try is either add the patient id to the checkout document as an extra field for later reference, or you could use `.parent()` to get it, since it is a subcollection, as explained on this [community answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60389279/flutter-get-parent-data-of-sub-collection-from-firestore). Let me know if any of these options work for your case.

Comment: I have successfully connected my patient id with the checkout page. Thanks for your help. But I'm still having issues showing checkouts. I have updated my question and code to make it more understandable. Once again, thanks for helping me.

Comment: ok, the comment I made is still relevant, you could use `reference.parent()` for that